# Failed to create instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

I cloned an ASP.NET Core project based on .NET 8. The IDE is VisualStudio 22 17.9, it compiles fine. But I got an error when I open the swagger page after startup, and the program doesn't end up running

```
InvalidOperationException: Failed to create instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionProvider'. Possible reason is cannot match the best constructor of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.EndpointMetadataApiDescriptionProvider'.
```

The project author is a colleague of mine who was able to run it correctly. I am using the same environment with him.

I checked Nuget and it should not be missing.
I tried reinstalling VisualStudio, but that didn't solve the problem.
I looked up the official Microsoft documentation and it looks like the IApiDescriptionProvider is all about attribute in the Controller, like [HttpGet], [HttpPost]. (I'm not sure)
I tried to run the front program and the request reported service exception.

Comment: You can use the `dotnet list package` command in the VS package manager console to check whether the package version installed by the current project is consistent with the correct project version.
And run `dotnet --list-sdks` in Command Prompt to check the locally installed SDK version.
Or you can create an api project to install the correct version of the relevant packages. If the error still appears exactly the same you can check the relevant project code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I upgraded VisualStudio (17.9.2 -> 17.9.3), the problem seems to have disappeared and now Swagger displays properly! But I don't know what happened, maybe refer to [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.9.3).

Before version 17.9.3 came out, I commented out the part about Swagger in Program.cs in order to get the program to work. Although Swagger doesn't work, the backend handles network requests fine.

```
// Comment out swagger-related code in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(); 
app.UseSwagger(); 
app.UseSwaggerUI(); 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Program.cs` you are missing :

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

[Check documentation](https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle)